# NullReferenceException during unittesting Db connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm getting error like below:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in magazyn.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This error is thrown in this method:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Storage storage = unitOfWork.storageRepository.GetByID(id.Value);
        if (storage == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return PartialView(storage);
    }
```

in this line:

```
Storage storage = unitOfWork.storageRepository.GetByID(id.Value);
```

Here my unit Test code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Details()
{
    int? a = null;
    var result = SC.Details(a);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(HttpStatusCodeResult));
    var code = result as HttpStatusCodeResult;
    Assert.AreEqual((int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, code.StatusCode);
    a = 1;
    result = SC.Details(a);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(HttpNotFoundResult));
}
```

I tried debugging this test and all values are passed correctly. In db there is a record with `Id=1`
What is wrong with this code?

@Update with Test initialization:

```
 [TestInitialize]
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Mock<IUnitOfWork> mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
        fakeRepo = mock.Object;
        SC = new StorageController(fakeRepo);
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the objects and properties of this line:

```
Storage storage = unitOfWork.storageRepository.GetByID(id.Value);
```

Are you sure that `unitOfWork` is correctly initialized? What about `storageRepository`? Check both of them with the debugger, setting a breakpoint on this line.

Answer (score 1):

I think Your Object `unitOfWork` is null try to create an instance of this object

```
UnitOfWork unitOfWork=new UnitOfWork();
```

Comment: I updated my code. UnitOfwork is OK. When I pass `Id=null` everything is ok and I get what I want and Assert pass. Problem is with `Id!=null`

Comment: try to make sure storageRepository has value other than null. i suspect when you pass id with some value storageRepository is throwing some exception and in turn it returns null.